# Is $f \mapsto 2f^1$ linear, where $f^1(x) = f(x+1)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

The book I got this exercise from says it is, but I don't understand why.

Doesn't it not satisfy $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$?

I would ask my lecturer, although I'm trying to teach myself this topic from a book so have nobody to ask.

Thanks

Comment: Linear from what to what?

Comment: $V$ is a vector space over $\mathcal{R}$, and $f \in V$. It just asks if this mapping is linear.

Comment: Be very careful to avoid double-use of the letter $f$. If $f$ is in your space $V$ of functions (which you have *not* specified) then the function, you should name your function something else, like $T$. So $(Tf)(x)=2f(x+1)$.

Comment: @someone That doesn't answer my question. $V$ appears to be some kind of vector space whose elements are some kind of functions defined on some kind of set. What kind of functions, and what kind of set? Please make all this clear and complete.

Comment: That's not what he or I wrote. Not clear who you are talking to, @GFauxPas

Comment: Yes, you definitely haven't told us what the vector space is.

Comment: Found it - $V$ is the space of all continuous real-valued functions on the unit interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you're being confused by the fact that $f$ is the argument here, not the function. It's true that $f$ might not satisfy $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ - however, that's not the issue at hand. What needs to be shown is that if $$h(x)=f(x)+g(x)$$
for all $x$, then $2h^1=2f^1+2g^1$ - that is, that
$$2h(x+1)=2f(x+1)+2g(x+1)$$
also holds for all $x$. That is, we're talking about constructing *functions* as linear combinations of other functions and we don't care so much about how $h$, $f$ and $g$ behave, but about how the given operation behaves upon them.

Comment: Got it, you're right, that was what was throwing me off. Thanks for your rapid response.

Answer (score 1):

Let $T$ be defined by $T(f)=2f^1$ where $f^1 (x)=f(x+1)$. 
Then $T(f+g)=2(f+g)^1$. We know that $2(f+g)^1(x)=2(f+g)(x+1)=2f(x+1)+2g(x+1)$ from the definition of the sum of two functions. Hence, $T(f+g)=T(f)+T(g)$.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Hadn't realised that we were to show that $T(f+g)=T(f)+T(g)$ rather than $f^1(x+y)=f^1(x)+f^1(y)$.